# ".msg" font colour different on Mac and Windows

Tags: css, email, fonts, outlook, msg

So I have this email template that I'm creating to be sent out. I tried sending the mail to myself first to check if it looks fine, on a Mac it looks perfectly fine with the right colours for the text and formatting.
But when i open the same ".msg" file on a PC, the font colour is messed up.
So for example i have a text

where the font colour is grey, but on a PC, it shows as black. Why is this happening?

Comment: Color management on MAC Vs PC are different, there will be some visual color different. Check this https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/color-differences-between-mac-and-windows-how-to-set-color-profile-scheme-on-wi

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is due to different font rendering of the Window and Mac. Mac OS  tries to render fonts exactly as they were designed, whereas Windows tries to alter them slightly to make them more readable. The possible solution is using Webkit-font-smoothing
Try including the following in your code

```
body {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And you can refer this link for knowing more about WebKit font-smoothing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth